# Force python to use a older version of a package - xgboost

Tags: python, pip, xgboost

I need to use an older version of xgboost package for compatibility issues. I am attempting to do that with `pkg_resources`:

```
import pkg_resources
pkg_resources.require("xgboost==0.90")
import xgboost
from xgboost import XGBRegressor
```

I get the following error:

```
VersionConflict: (xgboost 1.5.0 (/Users/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages), Requirement.parse('xgboost==0.90'))
```

When I try:

```
print(xgboost.__version__)
1.5.0
```

I have tried to `pip uninstall` and then `pip install xgboost==0.90`, but it still upgrades to `1.5.0`

In my python packages directory, I have the two xgboost packages installed.

```
/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages

xgboost
xgboost-0.90-py3.8.egg-info
```

Comment: you need to do `conda install xboost==0.9`